# select data based on multiple criteria (cloest value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using **MySQL**. I'm trying to build something and just can't find a solution to a problem.

I am selecting a value from the `lookup` table based on `my` table as shown in the below example.
**Select Criteria:** 
`my.id<>l.id` AND `my.route1=l.route1` AND `my.route2=l.route2` AND `my.utc=l.utc` 
where `my.stime is closest or same as l.stime`
ex) `my.id=2`'s col should get the `l.id=1, l.etime=7777` since `my.id<>l.id` and the rest are the same. 
ex) `my,id=5`'s col has options `l.id=3, l.etime=9999` and `l.id=4, l.etime=7979`  since `my.id<>l.id, my.route=l.route, my.utc=l.utc`. Yet, since `my.stime=2220 is closer to l.stime=2222` than `l.stime=3333` , `l.id=3, l.etime=9999` will be chosen.
ex) `my,id=6`'s col example is to select either value if "closest" is the same.
ex) `my,id=7`'s col example is to return NULL when the criteria is not met.

```
Table: lookup (l.)
id   route1   route2   utc   stime  etime
---|--------|--------|-----|-------|------
1     11        22     111   1111   7777
2     11        22     111   1111   8888
3     22        33     222   2222   9999
4     22        33     222   3333   7979
5     22        33     222   3335   8989

Table: my (my.)                      | result
id   route1   route2   utc   stime   |  l.id   l.etime    
---|--------|--------|-----|-------  |-------|----------|
2     11        22     111   1111    | 1       7777
5     22        33     222   2220    | 3       9999
6     22        33     222   3334    | 4or5    7979or8989
7     22        33     999   9999    | null    null
```

A new table should be created where the result is appended to the last col of `my`.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: subtract the values - then order by this subtraction, and LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a bit convoluted, but it's a starting point.

First, let's create an auxiliary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp AS
SELECT m.id mid, l.id lid, ABS(l.stime-m.stime) timediff
FROM my m JOIN lookup l
WHERE m.route1 = l.route1 AND m.route2 = l.route2 AND
      m.utc = l.utc AND m.id <> l.id;
```

From this table we can get the minimum `timediff` for each `my.id`:

```
SELECT mid, min(timediff) mtimediff FROM temp GROUP BY mid
```

Result:

```
mid         mtimediff
----------  ----------
2           0         
5           2         
6           1
```

Now we can find which rows in `lookup` have this `stime` difference, and choose the smallest `id`:

```
SELECT t.mid mid, min(lid) lid
FROM temp t JOIN (
    SELECT mid, min(timediff) mtimediff FROM temp GROUP BY mid
) mt ON t.mid = mt.mid AND t.timediff = mt.mtimediff
GROUP BY t.mid
```

This is the result:

```
mid         lid      
----------  ----------
2           1         
5           3         
6           4
```

And finally we use those `id`s to extract the data from the tables:

```
SELECT m.id, m.route1, m.route2, m.utc, m.stime, l.id, l.etime
FROM my m JOIN lookup l JOIN (
    SELECT t.mid mid, min(lid) lid
    FROM temp t JOIN (
        SELECT mid, min(timediff) mtimediff FROM temp GROUP BY mid
    ) mt ON t.mid = mt.mid AND t.timediff = mt.mtimediff
    GROUP BY t.mid
) ON m.id = mid AND l.id = lid;
```

Giving:

```
id          route1      route2      utc         stime       id          etime     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2           11          22          111         1111        1           7777      
5           22          33          222         2220        3           9999      
6           22          33          222         3334        4           7979
```

Comment: This was tested on SQLite, so the syntax may be slightly off for MySQL.

Comment: Great!!!!!! Thanks @Emilio Silva  However, when I do it separately its ok but when I do the last part, I am getting an error "Every derived table must have its own data. I guess I am messed up a bit with the alias.